# How to update a mongodb object using multiple selection criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

My schema structure looks something like this:

```
{
    "__v":0,
    "_id":ObjectId("5708423e897db8255aaaa9dd"),
    "podId":169400000005,
    "env":[
    {
        "type":"1",
        "id":3852000000035,
        "_id":ObjectId("5708423e897db8255aaaa9de")
    },
    {
        "type":"2",
        "id":3852000000040,
        "_id":ObjectId("5708423e897db8255aaaa9df")
    }
    ],
    "name":"Test Build",
    "parameters":[
    {
        "name":"sound.left",
        "type":"1",
        "paramName":"Left Sound Control",
        "paramType":"booleanParameter",
        "testValue":null,
        "liveValue":null,
        "_id":ObjectId("5708423f897db8255aaaaa0d")
    },
    {
        "name":"sound.right",
        "type":"1",
        "paramName":"Right Sound Control",
        "paramType":"booleanParameter",
        "testValue":null,
        "liveValue":null,
        "_id":ObjectId("5708423f897db8255aaaaa0d")
    },
    ...
    ]
}
```

I have 3 known variables: `podId` for `podId`, `codeName` for `parameters.name`, `envType` for `parameters.type`. Using them I want to update the object using `podId`, `codeName`, and `envType`, with a new variable `paramValue` that will contain the `testValue` value.

**What I've tried**

```
db.pods.update({
    podId: podId,
    parameters: {
        $elemMatch: {
            name: codeName,
            type: envType
        }
    }
}, {
    $set: {
        'parameters.$.testValue': paramValue
    }
});
```

I'm trying to update the `testValue` where `podId == podId`, `parameters.name == codeName`, and `parameters.type == envType`, but the above did not update anything.

I also tried

```
db.pods.update({
    podId: podId,
    parameters: {
        name: codeName,
        type: envType
    }
}, {
    $push: {
        parameters: {
            testValue: paramValue
        }
    }
},
    function(err) {
        if(err) throw err;
    });
```

basically taking what worked to build the object when I only had to compare the `podId`, and adding the extra criteria; it didn't work this time.

**edit**: fixed schema type Number to String

Comment: `parameters.type` is a string, are you sure you're matching on a string and not an integer?  i.e is `envType` `1` or `"1"`?

Comment: Whoops I typed it in my question incorrectly. `env.type`, `parameters.type`, and `envType` are all strings. I've updated the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let these are variables that you have in mongo shell:

```
> var podId = 169400000005
> var codeName = "sound.right"
> var envType = "1"
> var paramValue = "updatedParamValue"
```

This query you can try:

```
db.test.update({"podId":podId, "parameters.name" : codeName, "parameters.type" : envType}, {$set : {"parameters.0.testValue" : paramValue,"parameters.1.testValue" : paramValue}})
```

Depending upon which testValue you want to update, you can pass index to that.
**Update**

Following result i get after the update query:

```
db.test.find().pretty()
```

> {
>           "_id" : ObjectId("570c850ab9477f18ac5297f9"),
>           "__v" : 0,
>           "podId" : 169400000005,
>           "env" : [
>                   {
>                           "type" : "1",
>                           "id" : 3852000000035,
>                           "_id" : ObjectId("5708423e897db8255aaaa9de")
>                   },
>                   {
>                           "type" : "2",
>                           "id" : 3852000000040,
>                           "_id" : ObjectId("5708423e897db8255aaaa9df")
>                   }
>           ],
>           "name" : "Test Build",
>           "parameters" : [
>                   {
>                           "name" : "sound.left",
>                           "type" : "1",
>                           "paramName" : "Left Sound Control",
>                           "paramType" : "booleanParameter",
>                           "testValue" : "**updatedParamValue**",
>                           "liveValue" : null,
>                           "_id" : ObjectId("5708423f897db8255aaaaa0d")
>                   },
>                   {
>                           "name" : "sound.right",
>                           "type" : "1",
>                           "paramName" : "Right Sound Control",
>                           "paramType" : "booleanParameter",
>                           "testValue" : "**updatedParamValue**",
>                           "liveValue" : null,
>                           "_id" : ObjectId("5708423f897db8255aaaaa0d")
>                   }
>           ]
>   }

Thanks.

Comment: There are several pods in this schema, and the parameters array contains upward to a thousand parameter objects. I want to only update the `testValue` of specific objects where the `podId`, `parameters.name`, and `parameters.type` match.

Comment: So the query that I suggested isn't working? I have written the query keeping this thing in mind.

Comment: Yeah the `testValue` are still null.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, my mistake, I have updated the answer, please check.

Comment: Still nothing. I think the problem is the selection criteria, because it returns nothing when I use it in a find.

Comment: Impossible! May be you are using different name of the collection. I have inserted the document you gave fired the query and getting the result. Please post the steps that you are following if you want to get the solution.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing, turns out I was using a different collection name in my script, so I was looking at the wrong collection in the shell. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I thought the same :) Well if this solved your problem then please accept it as an answer. Thanks.